# Kandi 150 cc dune buggy won't start. I need to know whether I have a bad fuse or a blown starter motor

Tags: electrical, starter

When I turn the ignition switch to start the engine, the battery is on and charged, the lights and horn work, it shows that it is in neutral. I hold the brake pedal, but when I turn the key to crank the engine the starter does nothing. It makes no clicks or jolts, also the lights don't get dimmer when you try to start the motor. I need to know whether the fuse has gone bad or do I have a bad starter motor. How would I diagnose this problem?

Comment: A starter motor is rarely fused, but the starter relay may be. Check your fuses, and the starter relay itself if all fuses are OK.

Answer (score 1):

are there any other "lockout" circuits involved : in gear etc.
1) What you could try is to see if the starter motor works if you energise the solenoid directly.
2) If that works then you need to check the ignition switch is supplying a feed when turned to start.
You can do 1 or 2 in either order: if it is easier to check the ignition switch do that first.